# How to get custom table view cells to extend past end of table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I am trying to create a bookcase, similar to the one in iBooks, using a UITableView and my own subclass of UITableViewCell. Each custom cell represents a shelf in the bookcase. However, when the user scrolls past the end of the table (using elastic scrolling), the last cell is shown and then the white background of the table view is shown. How can I get extra shelfs to display after the last cell and before the first cell in the table, similar to how this is done in iBooks?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to add "fake"-shells as subviews for your table. They will have negative frame origins by `y` at the top and larger than table's `contentSize.height` `y` value for bottom ones